# ReactJS Consuming asp.net Rest Service

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

I'm completely new to consuming web services (API) using ReactJS; I have a webpage with a login form that excepts the username and password, then allows the user access by clicking a login button. The front-end is developed using ReactJS.

The front-end code:

```
 <form action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

...I'm using Postman to test the Web API Rest service running in behind the login page.
the results returned via postman are { "username": "Jdoe", "firstName": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "password": null, "token:" "ty77fakenumber" }

...My question is how do I get started in processing this API into my ReactJS page. Is there an HTTPServiceRequest that I need to implement? Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you please post your react code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in the componentDidMount lifecycle method and store the result in state.

example of a simple GET:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(‘/endpoint’)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => this.setState({users: json)))
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right. As it stands the form is just a standard HTTP POST - you'd need to change that too, wouldn't you? If you're going to use fetch then you'll need to serialize the form into the request as POST body.

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement suggest above I assume this refers to implies to HTTP Request required to be made to the Rest Service to get the results. I would recommend using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the data from the Rest Service. This is an async HTTP Request call to fetch the data.
Once you have the data, you will need a state management framework as well where you can store your data and use it as applicable on the component. In the React world, following are the popular state management framework:

1. [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview.html#content)
2. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction)

Of course, you can store the api response without these frameworks but I assume here you are going to use React more, state management is going to a hassle without a state management framework once you application gets bigger and more newer components keep getting added on.